# ImageMagick: Change aspect ratio of image without cropping and within a max width and height

Tags: image, imagemagick, image-resizing

*edit: End goal is a 2:1 aspect ratio, no cropping, and a max size of 1260x630. If the image dimensions are originally below 1260x630, they should stay below 1260x630.*

Struggling to word this well (which very well may be the reason I haven't found a good answer).

With ImageMagick I'm trying to resize an image down to 1260x630 provided the image itself is larger than the given size (width OR height).

Once resized I need to change the aspect ratio to a 2:1 without cutting off the image. I've accomplished this well enough with larger images using the following:

```
convert foobar-original.jpg \
   -resize 1260x630\>       \
   -gravity center          \
   -extent 1260x630         \
    foobar.jpg
```

A 1500x500 picture, for example, using the above, becomes first 1260x420 (with the resize) and then 1260x630 (via the extent), and the extra width is filled in with white background.

However, if the image starts off smaller, 800x200 for example, the image is *not* resized (as expected) but then is made to fit within a full 1260x630. This is not the desired result.

I would rather `-extent` simply affect the aspect ratio, adding on white as needed. So rather than the 800x200 image converting to 1260x630, with the 800x200 part of the image in the center, I would like the image to be converted to 800x400 (that 2:1 ratio), the extra height filled in with white space.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to set `-extent` to an aspect ratio, rather than a specific size or percentage. Something like

```
convert foobar-original.jpg \
   -resize 1260x630\>       \
   -gravity center          \
   -extent 2:1              \
    foobar.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

The first resize you are doing,

```
-resize 1260x630\>
```

operates as *"resize to 1260x630, but **only shrink larger images**"* (via the `>` flag).

There is a similar operation which you can apply,

```
-resize 1260x630\<
```

It operates as *"resize to 1260x630, but **only enlarge smaller images**"* (via the `<` flag).

If you combine both operations in one command you should be getting the result you want:

```
convert foobar-original.jpg \
   -gravity center          \
   -resize  1260x630\>      \
   -resize  1260x630\<      \
   -extent  1260x630        \
    foobar.jpg
```

Comment: Hey @KurtPfeifle, appreciate the response! The only problem is that the end result of your solution is still a 1260x630 image. Fwiw, running the > and the < command is the same as running neither: `-resize 1260x630\> -resize 1260x630\< == -resize 1260x630`.

Any ideas for keeping that final 2:1 ratio but NOT resizing up? Such that the final image size could be lower than 1260x630. An 800x200 image would become an 800x400 image.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter like three times without shift. Comment above is fully finished now. Cheers and thanks for making the edits to my original question by the way. It's definitely more readable multiline.

Comment: @SamThornton: ...or I misunderstood your intentions? I thought you *want* the `1260x630` end format?!

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit complicated. End goal is to have a 2:1 aspect ratio, without cropping, and a MAX image size of 1260x630. So, if the image was originally smaller than 1260x630, it should stay smaller, just with the aspect ratio changed.

Comment: I mean that the end result is the same. Running just `-resize 1260x630` without any extra operators ends up the same as running with both commands. In both cases all images, smaller and larger, are resized to 1260x630.

Comment: Figured that would be the case. I'm doing this all for a rails app as it is, so I'll write up an extra method. Thought I'd inquire about the possibility of doing it with one command though. Appreciate the help! If you want to add a note in your answer stating that to get my exact expected result I'd need to write a script, I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @SamThornton: You can probably use the `-fx` operator to achieve it without shell scripting. I'll have a go at it later, but right now I'll be away from keyboard for a while...

Answer (score 0):

I hat a similar problem an ended up to write a batch script:

```
@echo off
set magick_exe="C:\Programme Portable\ImageMagick-7.0.3-1\magick.exe"


for /R %%f in (*.png) do (
  call :body "%%f"
)

pause
goto :eof

:body
set FILE=%1
echo %FILE%

:start

%magick_exe% identify -format "%%[w]" %FILE% > w.txt
%magick_exe% identify -format "%%[h]" %FILE% > h.txt
set /p WIDTH=<w.txt
set /p HEIGHT=<h.txt
set /a HEIGHT2=%HEIGHT%*2


echo "size: " %WIDTH% x %HEIGHT% 

if  %HEIGHT2% gtr %WIDTH% (

  if %HEIGHT% gtr 630 (
     echo Resize hight to 630
     %magick_exe% convert %FILE% -resize x630 %FILE%
    goto :start
  )

  set /a SIZE_X=%HEIGHT%*2
  set /a SIZE_Y=%HEIGHT%

) else (

  if %HEIGHT% gtr 1260 (
     echo Resize width to 1260
     %magick_exe% convert %FILE% -resize 1260 %FILE%
    goto :start
  )

  set /a SIZE_X=%WIDTH%
  set /a SIZE_Y=%WIDTH%/2


)

echo "new size :" %SIZE_X% x  %SIZE_Y%

if %WIDTH% NEQ %HEIGHT2% ( %magick_exe% convert %FILE% -background white -gravity center -extent "%SIZE_X%x%SIZE_Y%"  %FILE% )

echo.
goto :eof
```